# What's the difference between gets.chomp() vs. STDIN.gets.chomp()?

Tags: ruby

Are they the same, or are there subtle differences between the two commands?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`gets` will use `Kernel#gets`, which first tries to read the contents of files passed in through `ARGV`. If there are no files in `ARGV`, it will use standard input instead (at which point it's the same as `STDIN.gets`.

Note: As echristopherson pointed out, `Kernel#gets` will actually fall back to `$stdin`, not `STDIN`. However, unless you assign `$stdin` to a different input stream, it will be identical to `STDIN` by default.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Had a hard time looking through that difference in the documentations.

Comment: Doesn't it fall back to $stdin, which just happens to often be the same as STDIN?

Answer (score 34):

`gets.chomp()` = read `ARGV` first

`STDIN.gets.chomp()` = read user's input

Comment: This is actually the simplest and best answer.

Answer (score 10):

If your color.rb file is

```
first, second, third = ARGV

puts "Your first fav color is: #{first}"
puts "Your second fav color is: #{second}"
puts "Your third fav color is: #{third}"

puts "what is your least fav color?"
least_fav_color = gets.chomp

puts "ok, i get it, you don't like #{least_fav_color} ?"
```

and you run in the terminal

```
$ ruby color.rb blue yellow green
```

it will throw an error (no such file error)

now replace 'gets.chomp' by 'stdin.gets.chomp' on the line below

```
least_fav_color = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

and run in the terminal the following command

```
$ ruby color.rb blue yellow green
```

then your program runs!!

Basically once you've started calling ARGV from the get go (as ARGV is designed to) gets.chomp can't do its job properly anymore. Time to bring in the big artillery: $stdin.gets.chomp

Comment: Ruby white belt here currently chiseling through the granite walls of Ruby the Hard Way and this chapter had me stumped until I found your explanation. Thanks for this!

Comment: Simple and clean example. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

because
if there is stuff in ARGV, the default gets method tries to treat the first one as a file and read
from that. To read from the user's input (i.e., stdin) in such a situation, you have to use
it STDIN.gets explicitly.