# Ruby: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - testfile (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby, file

I want to write something to a file.

```
# where userid is any intger [sic]
path = Rails.root + "public/system/users/#{user.id}/style/img.jpg" 
File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
  file.puts f.read
end
```

When this code is executed, I'm getting this error. I know this folder doesn't exist, but `File.open` with `w` mode creates a new file if it doesn't exist.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`File.open(..., 'w')` creates a file if it does not exist. Nobody promised it will create a directory tree for it.

Another thing, one should use [`File#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html#method-c-join) to build directory path, rather than dumb string concatenation.

```
path = File.join Rails.root, 'public', 'system', 'users', user.id.to_s, 'style'

FileUtils.mkdir_p(path) unless File.exist?(path) 
File.open(File.join(path, 'img.jpg'), 'wb') do |file|
  file.puts f.read
end
```

Comment: Just being curious: Why is is File.join advisable here? It joins the path components always with the platform specific separator (for instance, `\` on Windows). While there **are** cases, where this is what we want to achive, we usually try to stick with `/` on all platforms, because this gives less headache with respect of portability. In the case of the code posted here, I don't see why platform-specific file separators could be an advantage.

Comment: @user1934428 “we usually try to stick with / on all platforms, because this gives less headache with respect of portability”—besides this is nonsense, using `File.join` helps to avoid silly mistakes like the one in the OP: `Rails.root` does not end with a slash and using `+` gives `/railsrootpublic/` (note the slash miss above.)

Comment: @mudasobwa: In my rails console Rails.root + "bla/bla"
  
GIves correct path :)

Comment: @mudasobwa : it worked but I have to make some changes like Dir.mkdir only create directory not a directory tree, I used  FileUtils.mkdir_p : thnk for the help

Answer (score 63):

Trying to use `gets` inside a rake task? You may be seeing this error message:

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Did you try searching the error, and end up on this page? This answer is not for the OP, but for you.

Use `STDIN.gets`. Problem solved. That's because just using `gets` resolves back to `$stdin.gets` and rake is overriding the global variable so that `gets` tries to open a file handle that doesn't exist. Here's why:

[What's the difference between gets.chomp() vs. STDIN.gets.chomp()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523536/whats-the-difference-between-gets-chomp-vs-stdin-gets-chomp)

Comment: This also applies to use of `gets` inside of a Vagrantfile.

Comment: ...and this is now professionals write code. Yes, I ended up on this page, reading this  very answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and had to replace `open()` with `URI.open()`.

#### Minimal reproducible example

This gives the error

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = "https://www.example.com"
html_file = open(url)
# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://www.example.com
```

..but after you replace `open()` with `URI.open()` there's no error:

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

# Open the URL
url = "https://www.example.com"
html_file = URI.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also get this error when `File.open(..., 'w')` was unable to open the file i.e. because of protected folder access under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to create a file in Ruby.

I was trying to use the command below to create a new file:

```
File.new("testfile", "r")
```

and

```
File.open("testfile", "r")
```

but then I was getting the error below:

> (irb):1:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - testfile (Errno::ENOENT)

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I did not specify the right mode for the file. The format for creating new files is:

```
File.new(filename, mode)
```

OR

```
File.open(filename, mode)
```

And the various modes are:

```
"r"  Read-only, starts at beginning of file  (default mode).

"r+" Read-write, starts at beginning of file.

"w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
     to zero length or creates a new file for writing.

"w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
     or creates a new file for reading and writing.

"a"  Write-only, each write call appends data at end of file.
     Creates a new file for writing if file does not exist.

"a+" Read-write, each write call appends data at end of file.
     Creates a new file for reading and writing if file does
     not exist.
```

However, my command `File.new("testfile", "r")` was using the `"r"  Read-only` mode which was trying to read from an existing file called `testfile` instead of creating a new one. All I had to do was to modify the command to use the `"w"  Write-only` mode:

```
File.new("testfile", "w")
```

OR

```
File.open("testfile", "w")
```

**Reference**: [File in Ruby](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3/file)

Answer (score 0):

In my case is was because in method above I had:

```
Dir.chdir(some_folder)
```

so it changes current directory for next
`File.open` or `File.readlines` calls.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had a newline in my file name, e.g. `"paulgraham/attitude.md\n"`

Answer (score -1):

please use

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --disable-disk-cache
```

or

```
bundle exec jekyll bui --disable-disk-cache
```

Comment: You use bui or build , Its upon you, No need clarification. First test on your instance.