# How can I download an image from a website using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm using Selenium-Webdriver, OpenUri and Nokogiri to scrape a website. I want to download a particular image from said website to my Ubuntu computer. I tried a few different methods but each of them gives a different error message.

Here's my base code, which opens the website and gets the image url (everything after this I ran in my pry console):

```
require 'open-url'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

url = "https://www.google.com/"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
document = open(url).read
parsed_content = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
image = "https://www.google.com" + parsed_content.css('#hplogo').attr('src').value
binding.pry
```

---

**1)** Here's the first thing I tried to download the image:

```
download = open(image)
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/image.png')
```

For this, I got the following error:

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ~/image.png from (pry):44:in 'initialize'

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350321/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen), I tried adding a directory in the code:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p(image) unless File.exist?(image)
```

But I got the same error.

---

**2)** Next I tried this:

```
open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(image).read
end
```

and this returns

```
#<File:image.png (closed)
```

but the file isn't anywhere on my computer and I can't figure out what that message means.

---

**3)** Next I tried

```
IO.copy_stream(open(image), 'image.png')
```

which simply returned this:

> 5482

but again, I have no idea what that means and the file isn't anywhere.

---

**4)** Finally I tried

```
read_image = open(image).read
File.open(image, 'image.png') do |file|
  file.puts read_image
end
```

which outputs

> ArgumentError: invalid access mode image.png
>   from (pry):53:in 'initialize

---

**What am I doing wrong? Was I close with any of my approaches?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File open second argument is mode for file openning.

```
read_image = open(image).read
File.open('image.png', 'w+') do |file|
  file.write read_image
end
```

Your third variant works good.
5482 - length of file. File 'image.png' in same directory as your .rb file.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't expect it to be there! Is there some way I can specify the directory it should be in?

Comment: Instead of 'image.png' you can specify absolute path to file.