# "No such file" error when using `gets.chomp` in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted my seeds.rb file to have two paths based on some user input. For the sake of simplicity in this question I've stripped it down to just these two lines:

```
print "> "
res = gets.chomp
```

When I run rake db:seed, the following exception is raised:

```
▶ rake db:seed
> rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - db:seed
/home/me/work/my_app/db/seeds.rb:5:in `gets'
/home/me/work/my_app/db/seeds.rb:5:in `gets'
/home/me/work/my_app/db/seeds.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

Anyone know why this is happening, i.e. why gets.chomp in this context is causing the program to try to open a file named db:seed?

Comment: Technically I am. The arg to `rake` is `db:seed`. So that explains, a la @Glenn's answer, why it was trying to use `db:seed` as the input stream.

Comment: Yeah @Glenn's answer should help you. While using ARGV in Ruby the program looks for the input from somewhere other then the `STDIN`. Personally I think it's a bug that needs to be patched, but that's just my own opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `STDIN.gets.chomp` instead of `gets.chomp`.

See [What's the difference between gets.chomp() vs. STDIN.gets.chomp()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523536/whats-the-difference-between-gets-chomp-vs-stdin-gets-chomp) for the explanation.